# Is it possible to customize the Visual Studio autoformat?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio to develop a C/C++ library. I would like to know if there is a way to customize the autoformat tool (Ctrl+K,F) so that:

- It automatically break lines that are bigger than 120 columns
- Format a function/method parameter the following way:

  ```
  void myFunction(int parameterA,
          float parameterB,
          string paramterC)
  ```
- Format the brackets the following way:

  ```
  void myFunction()
  {
       // Code goes here...
  }
  ```

To summarize, I want something similar to what Eclipse does with it's autoformat (Ctrl + Shift + F) that can be customized by editing a XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those options are not good enough for you get [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/) it is a frontend for a whole slew of code formatting engines, you should be able to get the style that you want from it

Answer (score 3):

Tools | Options | Text Editor | C++

That is all I know that lets you edit how the code is formatted and the auto formatter uses these options (as few as they are).